Read email with attachments and convert to .eml file using Microsoft Graph API in C#
Need sample code to Read email with attachments and convert to .eml file using Microsoft Graph API in C#
Microsoft Graph API - 5.49.0 Version
Target Framework - Net 5.0
And please confirm whether am I using compactible versions or not.
var messages = _graphServiceClient.Users[""].MailFolders["inbox"].Messages.GetAsync().Result;

foreach (var message in messages.Value)
{
// From the "message" object, Able to retrieve BodyPreview, Subject, From Address and Has Attachments.
}

If HasAttachments is true and email contains attachment in the inbox but message.Attachments is null.
Need to know how to retrieve attachments from message object.
As well need to convert that email to .eml format and move the email to different folder from Inbox.

"using compactible versions" compact how? or did you mean to say "compatible" which is an entirely different thing?

You can filter messages with attachments
var result = await graphClient.Users[""].MailFolders["inbox"].Messages.GetAsync((rc) =>
{
    rc.QueryParameters.Filter = "hasAttachments eq true";
});

For each message, read it's MIMEContent and save the stream as .eml file.
foreach (var message in result.Value)
{
    var content = await graphClient.Users[""].MailFolders["inbox"].Messages[message.Id].Content.GetAsync();
}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-4-get-mime-content
